# React component created to render API response throws Unhandled Rejection

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[image]I'm new to React and struck while storing states of a rendered component.
Getting error as "redux.js:463 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Given action "SET_RECIPES", reducer "recipes" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined." Any suggestion on the error message please

Here is my code:

```
SearchComponent.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, FormControl, FormLabel, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { setRecipes } from '../actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class SearchOrder extends Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
        ingredients: '',
      dish: ''
    }
}  

    search() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let { ingredients, dish } = this.state;
    const url = `http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=${ingredients}&q=${dish}`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.props.setRecipes(json.results)
      });
  }


render() {
    return (
      <Form inline>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Ingredients</FormLabel>
          {' '}
          <FormControl 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="garlic, chicken" 
            onChange={event => this.setState({ ingredients: event.target.value })}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        {' '}
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Dish</FormLabel>
          {' '}
          <FormControl 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="adobo"
            onChange={event => this.setState({ dish: event.target.value })}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        {' '}
        <Button onClick={() => this.search()}>Submit</Button>
      </Form>        
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { setRecipes})(SearchOrder);


Action creator:
export const SET_RECIPES = 'SET_RECIPES';

export function setRecipes(items) {
  return {
    type: SET_RECIPES,
    items
  }
}

Reducer: index.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { SET_RECIPES } from '../actions';

function recipes(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_RECIPES:
      return action.items;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ recipes});
export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: What's `favoriteRecipes`? You don't define it anywhere.

Comment: @Jared Smith : Favorite recipes is supposed to be another action creator which i removed in my question as my first recipe reducer only not able to renderer it's state.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `recipes` reducer function like below.

```js
function recipes(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_RECIPES:
      return action.items || state; // return state if action.items is undefined
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In case **SET_RECIPES:** action.items could be undefined. We need to return the default state if its undefined using an OR expression check.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , but after adding OR condition, still the issue exists.

Comment: Did you try logging both your state and action variables inside the switch to see what happens.